# Creating a centered block of images within a Bootstrap Container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to have a group of centered images arranged in a certain way on the homepage of a bootstrap site. To look like the image below:

[image]

I want them to remain centered and then shrink when we go to mobile, with the "freeshipping block" not displaying so it just the two horizontal blocks below 750px.

I have set up a Plunker with the code I have

https://plnkr.co/edit/l6rbmEZQbqGZYifBmF5k?p=preview

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-12 customer-greeting">
  <p class="intro_text">My opening blurb of text</p>
  <div class="offerscontainer">
    <div class="offeroftheday">
      <a href="product_info.php?products_id=221">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/TQ6gwoO.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="freeshipping">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Xqw75nl.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="24hrdelivery">
      <a href="index.php?cPath=53">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/F3JTlas.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should I be adding float classes or should they all be bootstrap `col-8-sm`, `col-4-sm` etc?

PS - Should @queries be used in Bootstrap sites or should they pretty much all layout be handled in the HTML code with `col-8-sm` (bootstrap classes) etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this..

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <img class="img-responsive width-100" src="http://i.imgur.com/TQ6gwoO.jpg">
      <br>
      <img class="img-responsive width-100" src="http://i.imgur.com/TQ6gwoO.jpg">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img class="img-responsive width-100" src="http://i.imgur.com/Xqw75nl.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.width-100 { width: 100%; }
```

You can write col-md-* or col-sm-* depending on your requirement!

Comment: I have updated a Plunker at https://plnkr.co/edit/GGlUUGa1mHL3b5QoTeVH?p=preview , however, the far right box needs to be aligned directly next to other 2 horizontal boxes as in the picture above so they stay constantly packed together until they go to mobile/tablet. PS - Please explain the width-100 class?

Comment: Sorry, typo, forgot to put 100 in class. It's `.width-100` instead of `.width`

Comment: In plnkr remove `<style>` open and close tags in css and correct `.width` to `.width-100`